# Cannot push IonicApp/www to GitHub

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I pushed my newly initialized Ionic Apps to GitHub using the common practice:

```
git add .
git commit -m ""
git push origin master
```

But after this I went to check my Ionic project, everything was there except `www` folder. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: check your `.gitignore` file, this file contains the path of folders/files that shouldn't be on the github. Open this file using `nano .gitignore`, its in the same folder where you initialized git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file named .gitignore, which limits the content for git

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
*.log
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
log.txt
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.vscode/
npm-debug.log*

.idea/
.ionic/
.sourcemaps/
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
platforms/
plugins/
plugins/android.json
plugins/ios.json
www/
$RECYCLE.BIN/

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

you could edit the file(delete www/).

Comment: Thank you for ur answer! I wanna know the best practice here is to upload www to GitHub or not? And also about other folders that not uploaded? (I have a small project where I collaborate with around 3 people so could really use some advice.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Danni www folder generated after build, so no need for including it, I use default   
.gitignore configuration.

Comment: Usually you don't commit files and folders that you can re-create or are environment specific, e.g. www folder, node_modules folder, config files, temp files, cached files. If you are developing a PWA app, you only have to put www folder to the web server. You can deploy this folder using deployment tools.

Comment: @SašoKovačič Thanks I understand now!